# Azure Web Publish has stopped working - No Errors

Tags: azure, publish

I am unable to publish my website to either my Azure hosted staging site or my new Azure live site.

I HAVE published to each once but have been unable to do so since the first time.

I have tried...

- Regenerating the Publish profile
- Manually entering passwords
- Editing elements of the Database connection strings
- Comparing the *.pubxml files with another site that works

I'm tearing my hair out with this now.

This is all I can see - Any more log info would be nice, or an error message!

2>------ Publish started: Project: Communityweb, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>Transformed Web.config using C:\Development\Clients\Ministry\Pragmatic Agile Community\source\Communityweb\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed xslt\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\xslt\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Views\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed macroScripts\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\macroScripts\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed .\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config.
2>Auto ConnectionString Transformed .\umbraco\Xslt\Web.config into obj\Release\CSAutoParameterize\transformed\umbraco\Xslt\Web.config.
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I have solved this. This was, weirdly, created when I included the 'node_modules' folder in the project. It seems that the path length issue on the folder blew up the packaging process. Definitely one to look out for. A relevant error display in the output log would have been a bit handy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add 'node_modules' to the deployed files if you can possibly avoid it. If not you'll have to be selective. Gulp is a particular menace here for recursive nested node_modules folders that break the windows path limit.